# Flexbox: 3 divs, 2 columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox, so please bear with me. My html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

With flexbox, I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image: the following layout].

What's the simplest way I can achieve this **without setting a height for the container?** .one is expected to change in height.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this by setting `flex-direction` to `column`.

As requested, the width of the second `div` is static. I am using `calc` for the other 2 divs.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}
.one,
.three {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: cyan;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.two {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  order: 1;
  background: moccasin;
  width: 100px;
}
.three {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without setting a height for the container? Both .one and .three will change in height.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT .... Late answer , iI leave it since approach looks a little different from other even that it i think it very similar .. but not much choice about the way flex is working :)**

you may need to set an `height` to parent container and childs on first column. `order` will organize the flow of containers.

[codepen to check behavior and how it breaks while windows is reduced or content increased](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/XdXgdm)

```css
.one {
  background: #A1EB88;
}
.two {
  background: #E7AAF6
}
.three {
  background: #F7F467
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 50vh;/* height is needed to force wrapping */
}
.one,
.three {
  order: -1;/* bring them in front of other(s) */
  height: 50%;/* share the height (if three of them, then put it down to 33.33% to share evenly height avalaible) */
}
.two {
  flex: 1;/* equals height:100%; it will fill entire height */
  width: 200px;/* here your fixed width */
}
```

```html
<h1>test it also in full page mode </h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```